# ImageSharp - Mutate in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, optimization, .net-core, imagesharp

It's still in beta, but maybe someone knows..

I am using ImageSharp library for drawing some images (charts). I have something like this:

```
    Image<Rgba32> image = new Image<Rgba32> (width, height) 

    int y = 0;
    foreach (var label in labels)
    {
       var point = new PointF (0, y);
       image.Mutate(x => x.DrawText(label, labelFont, labelColor, point, new TextGraphicsOptions(true));
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this foreach? Can I somehow avoid repeating Mutate n times? 
Can something like this be done: 
image.Mutate(x=> x.MyFunctionContainingForeach())?

Comment: What exactly prevents you from doing that? Just call Mutate outside the loop and pass whole thing there?

Comment: Oh, that was easy! Tnx